# Dictionary as the class property and argument to a method

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> PersonProperties { get; set; }

    public Person(int id, Dictionary<string, string>personInfo )
    {
        ID = id;
        PersonProperties = personInfo;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp  in PersonProperties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value);
        }

    }
}
```

In the above example, do I need to initialize the class property `PersonProperties`?

something like

```
public Dictionary<string, string> PersonProperties { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

If yes, Why?

Comment: Yes you need,but you're doing it in the constructor, so everything is fine. Maybe you want to handle the case that it's null, for example by throwing an `ArgumentNullException `.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You mean check inside the constructor?

Comment: Yes, just throw if `null`: `PersonProperties = personInfo ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(personInfo));`. That's better than waiting for a follow up error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a bit different implementation:

1. Use *immutable* implementation; I doubt if we want to change `Id` once instance has been created; probably, the same is for `PersonProperties`.
2. Do not expose `set` for collection: why should we allow to `set`, say, `null` to the property?
3. We may want to be nice, and let key be *case insensitive*
4. We should validate constructor's input
5. Let's extract *UI* (`Console.WriteLine`) from *Business Logic* (constructor)

```
    public class Person {
      private readonly Dictionary<string, string> m_PersonProperties =
        new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

      public int ID { get; }
      
      // If we want to allow PersonProperties editing put it as
      // public IDictionary<string, string> ...
      public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> PersonProperties => 
        m_PersonProperties;

      public Person(int id, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> personInfo) {
        if (null == personInfo)
          throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(personInfo));

        ID = id;

        foreach (var pair in personInfo)
          m_PersonProperties.TryAdd(pair.Key, pair.Value);
      }

      public void Print() {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in PersonProperties)
          Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value);
      }
    }
```